# Move UIImage on top of another UIImage in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7oC7.png)

What i want to achieve:
CardBackImage is a subview of the ViewController. The view is placed somewhere (invisible with alpha = 0), i want to relocate it on top of deckPile and make it visible.

myCode:

```
let deckFrame = self.view.convert(deckPileView.frame, from: 
 deckPileView.superview)
        
print("deck frame is: \(deckFrame)")
        
fakeCardBack.frame = deckFrame 

UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [], animations: { [self] in  fakeCardBack.alpha = 1 }, completion: { _ in print("its works?") })
```

The problem with this code: The card is in the original position and not on deckPile position.

Please help.

Comment: It appears you want to do a "card flip" animation? If so, head over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `swift uiimageview card flip` ... you'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: The flip is here by mistake ,  its just a "random animation" to see where the card is drawen

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to do this directly with `UIImage`, but you can easily place the image inside a `UIImageView` and can set one view as a subview of another - since they are simply subclasses of `UIView`.

Here's some sample code to pin a view on top of another:

```
extension UIView {
    func pin(subview: UIView) { 
        subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        subview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        subview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        subview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        subview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true        
    }
```